# Pass argument via JNLP file into java web start application

Tags: java, arguments, java-web-start, jnlp

I'm beginner in Java programming, and I'm trying to make Java Web Start app. I need to pass some args to application, trough JNLP. When I hardcode values in web app, JNLP without args works fine, and start application. Also, when launch application from cmd with arguments, it's working. So I think that problem is in the JNLP file. When I try to launch app with JNLP that contains arguments, start failed with error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
```

JNLP file looks like:

```xml
   <application-desc main-class="SpeedScanLaunch" >
       <argument>http://localhost/TestApp/Dam/</argument >
       <argument>x</argument >
       <argument>50004</argument >
   </application-desc >
```

and Java class looks like:

```
import java.io.*;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class SpeedScanLaunch    
{
    public static void main(String args[])throws IOException
{   String p = args[0];
    String t = "/type:" + args[1];
    String id = "/id:" + args[2];
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, p);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, t);
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, id);
...
```

Does anyone know what the problem with JNLP is?
In addition, screnn freom JaNeLa:
[Screenshot from janela](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PK1AN.jpg)

And text report from JaNeLa:

```
JaNeLA Report - version 11.05.17


Report for file:/E:/eclipse_workspace/TestProjekt/bin/SpeedScanLaunch1.jnlp

Content type application/xml does not equal expected type of application/x-java-jnlp-file
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. No child element is expected at this point.
cvc-complex-type.2.4.d: Invalid content was found starting with element 'security'. No child element is expected at this point.
XML encoding not known, but declared as utf-8
Codebase '.' is a malformed URL!  Defaulting to file:/E:/eclipse_workspace/TestProjekt/bin/SpeedScanLaunch1.jnlp
Codebase + href 'file:/E:/eclipse_workspace/TestProjekt/bin/SpeedScanLaunch.jnlp' is not equal to actual location of 'file:/E:/eclipse_workspace/TestProjekt/bin/SpeedScanLaunch1.jnlp'.
Optimize this application for off-line use by adding the <offline-allowed /> flag.
Codebase '.' is a malformed URL!  Defaulting to file:/E:/eclipse_workspace/TestProjekt/bin/SpeedScanLaunch1.jnlp
Codebase '.' is a malformed URL!  Defaulting to file:/E:/eclipse_workspace/TestProjekt/bin/SpeedScanLaunch1.jnlp
Codebase '.' is a malformed URL!  Defaulting to file:/E:/eclipse_workspace/TestProjekt/bin/SpeedScanLaunch1.jnlp
Downloads can be optimized by specifying a resource size for 'SpeedScanLaunch.jar'.
The resource download at SpeedScanLaunch.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of download='eager'.
The resource download at SpeedScanLaunch.jar can be optimized by removing the (default) value of main='false'.
It might be possible to optimize the start-up of the app. by  specifying download='lazy' for the SpeedScanLaunch.jar resource.
Lazy downloads might not work as expected for SpeedScanLaunch.jar unless the download 'part' is specified.
```

Comment: 1) Be sure to check the JNLP using JaNeLA, available at my [share drive](https://drive.google.com/drive/#folders/0B5B9wDXIGw9lUnJaUjA2cmlVRE0). 2) Please use code formatting for code and code snippets, structured documents like HTML/XML or input/output.  To do that, select the text and click the `{}` button at the top of the message posting/editing form.

Comment: Andrew, thanks for the advice. I checked the file with JaNeLa, but i can't see the reason for this behavior of the application. I will add a picture of JaNeLa result, in my post.

Comment: *"I will add a picture of JaNeLa result, in my post."* I programmed JaNeLA to produce a **text report**, check the menus. Post the text instead.

Comment: Andrew, thanks again. I found error in jnlp, with your program. I was created two files for test, and forgot to change name in codebase.

Comment: Nice work on posting the text. 1) Is that the report from before or after correcting the code base? Aah.. now I'm reading the text report more closely - it seems like 'before'. 2) Is the problem fixed by the change in code base? Note that JWS can be quite poor at updating JNLP files. Be sure to completely uninstall previous JWS installations of the app. before retesting.

Comment: Yes, report is before change in code base. Your program was very useful.

Comment: *"Your program was very useful."* Glad it helped. :)